# Did I do this PowerShell problem correctly?

Tags: powershell, variables

Can someone check to see if I did this PowerShell problem correct?  Also, if you answer it could please explain what I did wrong.  That will help me to continue to learn. Thanks!

Problem 3.) Concatenate a and b so that it creates variable $c such that c -eq "this is the beginning this is the ending" Print the value of variable c.

**Here is what I tried and the output was: False**

```
$c = "this is the beginning this is the end"
($a + $b) -eq $c
```

Comment: Not enough info ... how are `$a` and `$b` defined? ... and whatever those may be, is there a (single) space between them?

Comment: ***So, this is your homework assignment.  ;-}*** --- When you are comparing strings, you have to be explicit/exact when using -eq, Secondly, You are not showing what is i $a, $b, but since you are doing a comparison, we could assume that $a, $b are pieces of the string $c. What you are showing is day one PowerShell training and experimentation stuff. Yet, I then assume you are new to PS and scripting since what you are showing is not unique to PowerShell. You'd have the same issue with any language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, and my assumptions made.

```
Clear-Host
$a = 'this is the beginning'
$b = 'this is the end'
$c = 'this is the beginning this is the end'

($a + $b) -eq $c
# Results
<#
 ($a + $b) -eq $c
False
#>

# Note the space added for the equality of the full string
($a + ' ' + $b) -eq $c
# Results
<#
True
#>

# Or
("$a " + $b) -eq $c
# Results
<#
True
#>


# Single quote is a literal string
# Double quote is normally used for string expansion or PowerShell variable, or formatting requirements.
```

Comment: Sorry about that I am very new to powershell and scripting.  I am having fun learning but I am only a couple weeks into this. You are correct with the variables.  Great guess! $a = "this is the beginning" and $b = "this is the ending"

Comment: So it should equal true from your different answers because basically $a and $b need to equal both strings combined together?

Comment: No worries, we all have to start from somewhere sooner or later. As to the comparison, yeppers, eq/match means just that. You are also not going to get C and a value, just the equality/matching status. As for learning, get and use these 3 books. Beg: Learn Windows PowerShell in a Month of Lunches 3rd Edition, Intermediate: Windows PowerShell Cookbook: The Complete Guide to Scripting Microsoft's Command Shell 3rd Edition, Advanced: Windows PowerShell in Action 3rd Edition. [Youtube is your friend](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%27beginning+powershell%27)

Comment: I appreciate you explaining everything and our teacher allows us to get help from anywhere on the internet because she said that's how she learned when she would run into problems as an IT technician.  I accepted your answer and thanks for the PowerShell book recommendations.  I'll look into them.

Comment: No worries. Our communities are here to help and learn ourselves. Happy studying and much success to you.